# How to get java jstat -gcutil result programmatically

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I would like to get the gc activities status of my running application from a point cut approach. The information i need will be the time taken for young gen gc and the full gc separately like in the jstat -gcutil.

I came across this class ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans but it is collector based, where the collection time involves both young and full gc.

Comment: You might start with the [Jstat.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/tools/jstat/Jstat.java/) source and create wrapper around it. (proposal not further investiated, but it seems feasible)

Answer (score 0):

jstat is using so called JVM performance counters. They can be access programmatically.

- add tools.jar from JDK to classpath
- use sun.misc.Perf class to access counters from target process

Sometime ago I have written library wrapping some APIs available in tools.jar, take a look https://github.com/gridkit/jvm-attach and [perf data example](https://github.com/gridkit/jvm-attach/blob/jvm-attach-api/src/test/java/org/gridkit/lab/jvm/perfdata/TestPerfData.java) in particular.

**PS**
Similar information can be retrieved from MBeans, young and old collectors have different MBean so you can track them separately. In addition, MBeans may send notifications on GC events.

Comment: will evaluate this API. Thanks for this.